# Use integrate barcode scanner with Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, barcode-scanner

I'm using an integrated barcode scanner for an app with Xamarin Forms and I want to set focus on an `Edit` field every time that I am on the view. However, I have another button on my page. So, is there a way to set Focus on my `Edit` at all times? ( I use focus because the barcode scanner complete automatically the field which is the focus )

Comment: You can focus on the `Edit` field programmatically, but if there are other UI elements on the page, the user will have to be able to focus on them in order to use them

Comment: okay, so I think that my problem will be more complicated because I want to be able to use an integrate barcode scanner ( no camera but physical button ) but the barcode can only field an Edit ( I think ), if you know something about that, ( it's this phone <https://www.mobile-barcode-scanner.com/fr/produits/et-l10/> ). It will be a pleasure. But it wasn't the point of this question, so don't worry. 

Thanks in any case for your time.

Comment: you really need to design your UI and workflow so that the user doesn't attempt to use the scanner when the app is not prepared for it

Comment: Do you know how to set focus on an Entry and make sure that keyboard doesn't appear. I used [Is there any way to hide software keyboard in Xamarin Forms during typing in Entry control?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71319956/19161629) but it's only work when the user press the control. However, when I use something like `myControl.Focus()`, keyboard appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue to my problem.

In my xaml file

```
<Entry x:Name="myEntry"
       Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />
```

In my c# file

```
private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    this.myEntry.Focus()
}
```